Failed to launch anaconda navigator on wsl2
Followed installation instructions for linux on this page.
Installed some apps from here, to test out. Everything works.
Following instructions here. I should be able to launch anaconda navigator.
However I get the following error:
An exception occurred during fetching list of system display settings.

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)

Tried to comment on the answer's response and avoid a new question but not enough reputation points.
I have already reinstalled it, as suggested, and run checksum, no mismatches.

sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx libglib2.0-0
# Set DISPLAY Environment Variable 
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0

Restart your WSL instance to ensure all changes take effect:
wsl --shutdown
wsl


Anaconda docs first steps already instructs to install libgl1-mesa-glx, but why libglib2.0-0? And what does the second command do?
